# Starting a new activity from a thread

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, runnable

I need to call a new activity from a thread class like this:
   `Intent i = new Intent(getContext(),GameOver.class);`
and when i call `startActivity(i)` it gives me an error saying that the method is undefined for my class.
Can anyone tell me how do resolve this issue?
Thanks!
Here is the full run method of the thread:

```
/*starts running the thread*/
    @Override
    public void run(){
        while(run){
            Canvas c = null;
            try {
                c = surfaceHolder.lockCanvas(null);
                synchronized (surfaceHolder) {
                    if (mode == STATE_RUNNING){
                        /*if user has no more lives, he lost*/
                        if(Global.lives == 0) lose();
                        doDraw(c);
                    }
                }
            } finally {
                // do this in a finally so that if an exception is thrown
                // during the above, we don't leave the Surface in an
                // inconsistent state
                if (c != null) {
                    /*unlocks the canvas and shows the image drawn by the doDraw method*/
                    surfaceHolder.unlockCanvasAndPost(c);
                }
            }
```

Where `lose();` is the method who's code is on the start( intent ).

Comment: please post your full code

Comment: send a broadcast or move the logic that handles the start of the new activity to the main thread

Comment: i wanted to do so, but maybe there is a simpler way.

Comment: is lose() a method in your activity?

Comment: No, it's the method in the thread.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, startActivity is a method of Contex, so you will need to pass reference to a valid Context..

Second thing is, that as far as I know, activity can be started only from main (GUI) thread. There is several ways how to do it, one of them is for example something like this:

```
Handler handler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());

handler.post(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        Intent intent = new Intent (MyActivity.this, NextActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
});
```

Comment: No, that won't work because my class doesn't extend activity. I need to inform the caller class that something has occurred but i don't want to use the Broadcast Receiver.

Comment: I think, in that case you have a problem :-) you will need some context to start new activity :-). If you don't have a chance to pass context, you will need some ugly workaround with static variable/function on one of existing Activity or service in your app, but this is ususally not what you really want..